# MS Scrum template installed correctly but not found

Tags: tfs, scrum

I installed Microsoft Scrum 1.0 template from their website, it installed with no errors but it is not being shown in the Templates list when I try to create a New Team Project. There is only MSF Agile and MSF CMMI.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you choose upload, you need to browse c:\Program Files\Microsoft\Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0\Process Template, which is the folder that contains the ProcessTemplate.xml root file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to upload the process template to your server:

In the Visual Studio 2010 choose from the menu TEam -> Team Project Collection Settings -> Process Template Manager. In the dialog choose Upload

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post that details the steps to upload and install the template.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2010/07/19/microsoft-visual-studio-scrum-1-0.aspx